# How to keymap reverse-search (Ctrl+R) in iTerm to a different key combination

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, iterm

I am trying to map the reverse-search-history (Ctrl+R) command to a different command combination in iTerm but not sure how? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It has nothing to do with iTerm, this is done by `bash` independently of the terminal emulator. Read the bash documentation on configuring `readline`: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bindable-Readline-Commands.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands

Comment: Why can't iTerm map this key combination the same way it does with other commands?

Comment: The commands aren't bound by iTerm in the first place, they're bound by `bash` and `zsh`. You get the same bindings with `xterm`, `gnome-Terminal`, etc., don't you?

Comment: Please ask for your question to be migrated to SuperUser.com, it's not a programming question.

Comment: You could use BetterTouchTool or `osascript` to make a key combination alias. Also, google `bindkey` or `bind` commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The person who mentioned `readline` is correct.

You can edit your bindings using the `bind` command (try `help bind`).

For this particular question, let's see what's bound to Control-R:

```
$ bind -P |grep C-r
re-read-init-file can be found on "\C-x\C-r".
reverse-search-history can be found on "\C-r".
revert-line can be found on "\M-\C-r".
```

Ok. One of those is just `\C-r` which means Control-R. Let's double-check:

```
$ bind -q reverse-search-history
reverse-search-history can be invoked via "\C-r".
```

`man readline` includes:

`` reverse-search-history (C-r)
      Search  backward  starting  at  the current line and moving `up'
      through the  history  as  necessary.   This  is  an  incremental
      search. ``

That looks right. How do we change it? Let's assume you want to use ⌘-B instead. That's Meta-b (aka `\M-b`) in readline-speak.

Let's try it out:

```
$ bind '\M-b:reverse-search-history'
$ bind -q reverse-search-history
reverse-search-history can be invoked via "\C-r", "\M-b".
```

Pressing ⌘-b now triggers reverse search just like Control-R. Control-R is still bound though. We can fix that:

```
$ bind -r '\C-r'
$ bind -q reverse-search-history
reverse-search-history can be invoked via "\M-b".
```

This change will hold for the current shell session, but will vanish the next time a shell is invoked. To make the change persistent, do the following:

```
$ echo '"\M-b": reverse-search-history' >> ~/.inputrc
```

Now `~/.inputrc` contains the desired binding. Any program that uses it for `readline` configuration (including your shell) will now use the binding you specified.

Comment: Exceptional response. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I had to figure this out before stackoverflow existed. I know how frustrating this can be.